# i want to add more coloumn to the parse user table in parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
// Set up a new Parse user
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(password);
user.put(phone, "phone no");
```

i have LREADY READED THE PARSE DOCS AND WHAT I GET FROM THEIR IS THAT I HAVE TO PUT KEY AND ITS VALUE LIKE THIS  user.put(phone,"phone_no");

but it is not working please help me

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the other way around?

```
    user.put("phone no", phone);
```

At least that's how I understand it..

Comment: still not getting data in new coloumn phone..;(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a call to user.saveInBackground();
The following is from the documentation on Parse website - https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

```
`ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user.put("phone", "phone no");
```

You enter in the the name of the column you want to add as a string, I believe you missing the quotes.